# adding favorite items of a table view in a new table view at ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have an app that has a tab bar with two parts. one favorite that is empty at the begining and one for list of items shown in a table view and when i click on each another page opens and it shows some information.
i want to add a button at information page and when i click on it adds the title to the favorite bar.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access to self.tabBarController and create some method to update title of controller at specified index.

Edit: call this on button pressed

```
var favoriteVC: FavoriteViewController = self.tabBarController.childViewControllers.objectAtIndex(0) // index of favorite controller
favoriteVC.addNewItemToMyItems("New item")
```

Comment: would you explain more? im new to ios